# Laravel 5.3 Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buble'

Tags: php, laravel, npm, gulp, webpack

I'm following the Laravel passport video tutorial on Laracasts and kept getting the below error, so I have taken a fresh install of Laravel using the Laravel install tool but I'm still getting the error:

```
laravel new test

cd test

gulp

Error: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buble' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test' resolve 'buble' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test
```

This is a fresh install with no changes, am I missing something from the install process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to do `npm install` before using gulp.

**Bublé** is a ES2015 compiler (light version of Babel). 
They come with Laravel, but you must previously install them, via `npm install`.

Comment: hello, sorry I should have added, I have run NPM install after the installation, the problem seems to be something with webpack rather than NPM but I have very little experience with webpack

Comment: What do you get as a response after running `npm ls buble` in the project directory?
What is your node version?

Comment: laravel-elixir-webpack-official@1.0.5
  └── buble@0.12.5 NPM Version: 2.15.1

Comment: I meant node.js version. Run `node -v` if it's not 6.4.0 or above that's most likely the issue. So you'll need to upgrade node.js

Comment: ah I'm running node version 4.4.3 Where can I get node 6.4.0? The main node website only has V4.5.0

Comment: [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)  get the 6.5.0 version. After you download and install it. Check your version again with `node -v`. If it's 6.5.0 now, delete node_modules from the project and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Thank you that solved the issue thank you

Comment: Glad I could be of help @twigg :)